# WorksheetFunction.Index calls error type mismatch run time error 13

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, worksheet-function

```
oTemplateStartRow = 3
```

arrLast is array with (1 to 6385, 1 to 6) dimension

I have these code line:
Trying to get only second column of array and paste this column into second column of activesheet

```
Cells(oTemplateStartRow, 2).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 2)
```

It calls error:

> type mismatch run time error 13.

What is reason for that?

PS:
This test procedure works fine but when I work with my variables (arrLast, oTemplateStartRow ) it is not working:

```
Sub PartOfTheArray()
Dim ar(1 To 20, 1 To 5)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To 20
        For j = 1 To 5
            ar(i, j) = i + j * 0.01
        Next j
    Next i
    Cells(1, 1).Resize(20, 1).Value = ar ' столбец 1 '
    Cells(1, 2).Resize(20, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 0, 2) ' столбец 2 '
    Cells(1, 3).Resize(10, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 0, 4) ' неполный столбец 4 '
    Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value = ar ' строка 1 '
    Cells(2, 4).Resize(1, 5).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 7, 0) ' строка 7 '
    Cells(3, 4).Resize(1, 3).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(ar, 9, 0) ' неполная строка 9 '
End Sub
```

Comment: Would help to show your full code for the non-working version, including all variable declarations

Comment: @TimWilliams, code is very big, very very long, that's why I am showing part. Maybe You will ask some things, and I will give only them.

Comment: As a general note, when you get an error. Goto into debug, and test the following in the Inmmediate window:
?oTemplateStartRow   -> needs to return a number >=1
?UBound(arrLast, 1)    -> needs to return a number >=1
?WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 2) -> see if that returns your data
... And so on

Comment: @j74nilsson, ?oTemplateStartRow
 returns 3;
?UBound(arrLast, 1)
  returns 6385;
?WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 2)
 returns error type mismatch

Comment: You can't write a smaller version which still has the error?  Typically that's the best way to find the problem, rather than us guessing about the not-shown parts.

Comment: @TimWilliams, can I give github repo link of it here?

Comment: You can paste any link here...

Comment: What is your `arrLast` filled with?

Comment: @TimWilliams, https://github.com/AzizxonZufarov/vbacode (look for >>>error comment)

Comment: That's a lot of code to go through and it's late for me...

Comment: Try splitting up the problem line:  `Dim res: res = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 2):  Cells(oTemplateStartRow, 2).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value = res`  Which line errors?

Comment: @TimWilliams res=WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 2) is error line

Comment: If arrLast is a twodimensional Array and you are trying to get one of it's values, why not just access it directly by arrLast(0, 2)?

Comment: @j74nilsson not one of its value, whole column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test what type of value in your arrLast that breaks your code test this in your code:

```
    With Worksheets(XPList)
         'Проходим по столцбам Артикул, Наименование  и записываем данные
         .Cells(oTemplateStartRow, 1).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value = arrLast

'###ADDED:
         for i=1 To Ubound(arrLast,1)
            debug.print i, TypeName(arrLast(i,2))
            if TypeName(arrLast(i,2))="TestType" then arrLast(i,2)="X"
         next

         .Cells(oTemplateStartRow, 2).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 2) '>>>error
         
         
          
         'Проходим по всем столбцам блока текущий и записываем данные (столбцы Контрагенты и Итого)
         .Cells(oTemplateStartRow, CurrentBlockStartColumn).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 3) '>>>error
         .Cells(oTemplateStartRow, CurrentBlockStartColumn + 1).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 4) '>>>error
         .Cells(oTemplateStartRow, CurrentBlockStartColumn + 2).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, 5) '>>>error
         .Cells(oTemplateStartRow, CurrentBlockStartColumn + 3).Resize(UBound(arrLast, 1), 1).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Index(arrLast, 0, arrExistTotalColumn) '>>>error
    End With
```

What output will that give you? Then evaluate removing all values of this type by replacing "TestType" with the TypeName given and see if it works.
/J

Comment: Or even better if you have many values (;=newline):
`Dim tmp;
for i=1 To Ubound(arrLast,1);
tmp = TypeName(arrLast(i,2));
arrLast(i,2)="X";
on error resume next:;
WorksheetFunction.Index arrLast, 0, 2;
if err.number=0 then;
debug.print i, typename(tmp);
exit for;
end if;
err.clear;
next`

Comment: WorksheetFunction.Index does not work if passed array contains even one empty element?

Comment: It works with "Empty" when I test it. It must be some other value in your array? Test the code in my comment above. `Dim x(1 To 10, 1 To 10): x(2, 2) = Empty: Debug.Print TypeName(WorksheetFunction.Index(x, 0, 2)(1, 1))` works.

Comment: Sorry - one issue in the code of my first comment. Replace `debug.print i, typename(tmp)` with: `debug.print i, tmp`

Comment: It might be the case that OutputArray contains the value Null. Then you would get this issue as `If OutputArray(i, 1) = vbNullString Then` does not check for a Null value. That would be `If Isnull(OutputArray(i, 1)) Then`

Comment: https://ibb.co/JcgHDzx

Comment: Run the code in the first comment with the modification stated in the fourth. This will tell you what type value that gives you the error. On the screenshot shared we only see the first 7 items out of 6385 which are all strings. It will most certainly be something in that list that is not a "String" that makes the Index function break. I would guess it is a "Null".

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the `Type Mismatch` error with `Index`:

**EDIT**: added VBA replacement for Index which can handle the "bad" array value.  Also will be faster than using `Index`, which is pretty slow if called in a loop.

```vb
Sub tester()
    
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, res
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    ReDim arr(1 To 10, 1 To 5)
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        arr(r, c) = "R" & r & "-C" & c
    Next c
    Next r
    
    arr(5, 2) = Null '### ok if you comment this out
    
    res = WorksheetFunction.index(arr, 0, 2) 'Error 13

    'this works even with the Null...
    Place2DArray Slice(arr, 2, False), Range("E5")   'False to get column
    Place2DArray Slice(arr, 4, False), Range("F5")
    
    Place2DArray Slice(arr, 2, True), Range("G5")   'true to get row

End Sub

'Return a row or column from a 2D array `arr`, at index `indx`
'  Pass no value or True to `getRow` to extract a row, or False
'   to extract a column
Function Slice(arr, indx As Long, Optional getRow As Boolean = True)
    Dim rv, i As Long, ubr, lbr, ubc, lbc
    lbr = LBound(arr, 1)
    ubr = UBound(arr, 1)
    lbc = LBound(arr, 2)
    ubc = UBound(arr, 2)
    If getRow Then
        ReDim rv(1 To 1, lbc To ubc)
        For i = lbc To ubc
            rv(1, i) = arr(indx, i)
        Next i
    Else
        ReDim rv(lbr To ubr, 1 To 1)
        For i = lbr To ubr
            rv(i, 1) = arr(i, indx)
        Next i
    End If
    Slice = rv
End Function

'place a 2D 1-based array on a worksheet starting at `rng`
Sub Place2DArray(arr, rng As Range)
    rng(1).Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
End Sub
```

Something in your array doesn't work with `Index()` - here it's `Null` but your array may contain some other problem type.

Comment: arrLast contains empty columns (third, fourth, fifth,sixth columns). Is it reason? If yes, what should I do for getting only one column in this situation?